# http.client.requests not working in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, micrometer, health-monitoring, spring-micrometer

I am using Rest template to make API third party API request from my server.

[image]

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

After doing all this I am not able to view `http.client.request`

[image]

I wanted to know where I am missing, why `http.client.request` not coming. I also made request various time but then also I didn't get anything

Comment: How are you using a `RestTemplate`? Which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using spring boot version: `2.7.0` and making request like this
`restTemplate.postForEntity(hostname + url,createPostHttpEntity(requestBody, headers),responseClass);`

Comment: Spring Boot 2.7 doesn't have build in observability so you would need some additional ibrary. Spring Boot 3 has. I understand how you are using `RestTemplate` (that is kind of obvious) but are you using an injected `RestTemplate` (which you should) or are constructing it as you need it (which you shouldn't do ).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using injected `RestTemplate` only. Can I know which library are you telling?

Comment: Sorry my bad there is an interceptor that registers the metrics. DId you use the `RestTemplateBuilder` to create the `RestTemplate` or did you create it yourself? If you used the builder you should have metrics.